# Unsupportable bitmap format. Byte array to SoftwareBitmap (UWP C#)

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

Help cant convert byte array to SoftwareBitmap. Error: 
[image]

```
WriteableBitmap b = new WriteableBitmap(Weight*frame_size,Height*frame_size);
// WriteableBitmap uses BGRA format which is 4 bytes per pixel.
byte[] imageArray = new byte[b.PixelHeight * b.PixelWidth * 4];
for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.Length; i += 4)
{
    imageArray[i] = 0; // Blue
    imageArray[i + 1] = 0;  // Green
    imageArray[i + 2] = 255; // Red
    imageArray[i + 3] = 0;
}
//Open a stream to copy the image contents to the WriteableBitmap's pixel buffer 
using (Stream stream = b.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(imageArray, 0, imageArray.Length);
}

SoftwareBitmap outputBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(b.PixelBuffer,BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,b.PixelWidth,b.PixelHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_CreateFromSoftwareBitmap.htm) method supports `BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8` format. The corresponding    `CanvasBitmap`'s Format for `BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8` is `DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized`. According to the [Pixel formats](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/PixelFormats.htm) of Win2D:

> If in doubt, pixel format B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized and CanvasAlphaMode Premultiplied are good defaults for most purposes.

You may need to set the `BitmapAlphaMode` to `Premultiplied` with method `CreateCopyFromBuffer(IBuffer, BitmapPixelFormat, Int32, Int32, BitmapAlphaMode)` when create the `SoftwareBitmap` to make the format compatible.

```
SoftwareBitmap outputBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(b.PixelBuffer, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, b.PixelWidth, b.PixelHeight, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
```